# Python Code Error: I can't add more than one "product" to my app

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this supplyChain demo app, made it for learning. I have a problem in it though. I cannot add more than one "product", "chain", or "type/destination". What can I do to fix it?

Here it the code:

```
print("Welcome to supplyManage by PCMX ./Code\nType in .{help} to get started with commands")

initcmd = input("./: ")

if initcmd == ".{help}":
    print(
        "Welcome to supplyManage\n"
        "Start by creating chain: ./create{}\n"
        "Add product to chain by ./chain/pro\n"
        "Add chain type by: ./chain/type\n"
        "Add destination by: ./chain/desti\n"
        "Type ./chain/log for all lists printed\n"
        "As of now, only one chain can be made per program"
        "Now rerun program to load\n"
    )


if initcmd == "./create{}":
  ask = input("Name of Chain: ")
  chain = ask
  chainpro = [] # List of products 
  chaintype = [] # List of Types
  destichain = [] # final place of products
  print("Chain {} is made.".format(chain))
  initcmd = input("./: ")

if initcmd == "./{}/pro".format(chain):
  productname = input("Name of Product: ")
  chainpro.append(productname)
  initcmd = input("./: ")

if initcmd == "./{}/type".format(chain):
  typepro = input("Shipping Type: ")
  chaintype.append(chaintype)
  initcmd = input("./: ")

if initcmd == "./{}/desti".format(chain):
  prodesti = input("Final Place of Product: ")
  destichain.append(prodesti)
  initcmd = input("./: ")

if initcmd == "./{}/log".format(chain):
  asklogprint = input("We are going to export as a txt file. y or n")
  if asklogprint == "n":
    initcmd = input("./: ")
  elif asklogprint == 'y':
    import json
    with open("DataProducts.txt", 'w') as savepro:
      savepro.write(json.dumps(chainpro, chaintype, destichain))
    initcmd = input("./: ")
  else:
    print("Invalid Response")
    inicmd = input("./: ")
```

Comment: This should be in some sort of loop.  When you execute one command, in your `if` statements you do ask for the next command, but you will eventually get to the end of the code and the program terminates, thus all variables are released.  Is the program supposed to be like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to nest everything in a while loop and have that act as a switch to keep the program running, and use similar logic to allow for multiple inputs at once.

For multiple inputs:

```
x = 0
arr = []
while x != 'done':
    x = input('enter a number: \n')
    for i in x:
        if x != 'done':
            arr.append(x)
```

This code above allows consecutive inputs until the user types 'done', and appends values to an array.  As rayryeng pointed out, you also want to nest everything a similar while loop in order to keep the program running.